# /usr/bin/env: python, No such file or directory

Tags: python, shell

I write code working with mapreduce in Ubuntu System in Vmware. Now I have two snippets of code with the same header but one is right and another one report

```
/usr/bin/env: python  
: No such file or directory
```

error. This is the one report error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rowNum = 100
    colNum = 100
    for line in sys.stdin:
        type, row, col, val = line.strip().split()
        if type == 'A':
            for k in range(colNum):
                print '%s,%s\t%s:%s,%s' %  (row, k, type, col, val)
        elif type == 'B':
            for k in range(rowNum):
                #index1, index2, element = line.split(',')
                print '%s,%s\t%s:%s,%s' % (k, col, type, row, val)
        else: continue
```

This is correct one. It works well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  

import sys

# input comes from STDIN (standard input) 
if __name__ == '__main__':
        for line in sys.stdin:
            # remove leading and trailing whitespace  
            line = line.strip()
            # split the line into words  
            words = line.split()
            # increase counters  
            for word in words:
                # write the results to STDOUT (standard output);  
                # what we output here will be the input for the  
                # Reduce step, i.e. the input for reducer.py  
                #  
                # tab-delimited; the trivial word count is 1  
                print '%s\t%s' % (word, 1)
```

I search the whole website and try their method to fix it. But none of them worked, including finding the path is correct or not, checking whether there is a                                     carriage return. I was stun in them whole day because they have the same header but one can not find it.

Comment: Did you make a copy of the working script and edit that? If so, what are you using to edit the file?

Comment: @cricket_007 I copy the header from second snippet to the first one. I use gedit to do this

Comment: @cricket_007 I just type it (no copy) again and it yields to the same error

Comment: Related?  http://askubuntu.com/a/784600

Comment: @cricket_007 It seems not the case..

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the error message prints the word 'python' in one line and the ': No such file or directory' in the next line, suggests that there is some invisible character after *python*. Do a hexdump of your file to find out.

Comment: could you give a example of this? I read this and have no idea how to use the command..New to Linux.

Comment: you will need to use an editor that can show hex codes.  I think vim can do with: 
:%!xxd to switch into hex mode
:%!xxd -r to exit from hex mode

Comment: @Anderson: You can simply use `od`, for example  `head -n 3 MYSCRIPT | od -cx`. Depending on your installation, it could be that there is also `hexdump`or `hexedit` installed.

Answer (score -1):

You have an colon : after the /usr/bin/env   you need to remove it.

Comment: I double check it again. I do not see colon in my code.

Comment: I rechecked your note I saw the: /usr/bin/env: python  
: No such file or directory and assumed that was the header in you file which it was not